# Show all running applications in ListBox and kill them on button click in c#

Tags: c#, process, listbox, items

I want to collect processes in listbox like this:

> app.exe
>   otherapp.exe

but I just get:

> System.Diagnostics.Process(app.exe)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process(otherapp.exe)

My code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] prs = (Process.GetProcesses());

        foreach (Process pr in prs)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(pr));
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();

        string item = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        //item.Kill();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the same code just a small change**

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(pr.ProcessName));
```

**So in short**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Process[] prs = (Process.GetProcesses());

             foreach (Process pr in prs)
             {

                listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(pr.ProcessName));
             }
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

**Reason:**

You just had to use the Property `ProcessName` property on the Instance

Answer (score 0):

First you should store the process name:

```
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(process.ProcessName);
    }
```

After that you can use the name to get the process(es) and kill it/them:

```
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx for more information about the process class.